# Titanium android app size increased after installing the application - how to fix?

Tags: android, installation, size, titanium

I am developing a mobile application using Titanium for iPhone and android. Apk file size is around 6MB. But  after installation, on checking under Manage applications it shows the app size is 12MB.

How could this happen??

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the size of installed app will always be more than the .apk file

Secondly,The apk files for Titanium also contain the runtimes neccessary to interprete the JavaScript to native Android code.

Till the version 1.8.0,Titanium used to package both V8 and Rhino runtime support into the .apk files.Not sure if that was practice was stopped after 1.8.0 .

Also another aspect is the size of the image files used.Make sure that you make use of .png files,because .jpg can increase your build size.

To reduce build size further consider using  [Proguard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)

Comment: I'm using version 1.8.0 and the apk file size is 6.5MB, then I changed to version 2.1 it will become 9.1MB and after installation it shows 15.84MB under manage applications.

Comment: That is normal Titanium behaviour.You can try changing the runtimes from the tiapp.xml to see the changes in size(try Titanium SDK 2.0.2 with V8.It gives lesser size).Also I would suggest using Proguard.